# SEO when creating many URLs for a page that differ only by the name of the person that created the link

Tags: seo, url, duplicate-content

I'm developing a referral system for my website, and the way it works now is to generate an unique URL like `www.example.net/public/referral/UNIQUE_URL`. This page is just a normal registry page like the one found in `www.example.net/public/registry`, but with the text "You were referred by: NAME_LASTNAME_OF_USER". Example:

**Registry page** `www.example.net/public/registry`

> *name*:_________
>
> *last-name*:_________
>
> *email*:______
>
> *password*:______

**Referral page** `www.example.net/public/referral/UNIQUE_URL`

> *name*:_________
>
> *last-name*:_________
>
> *email*:______
>
> *password*:______
>
> *You were referred by: NAME_LASTNAME_OF_USER*

How is this going to affect the SEO of the site? It will be better to use the same registry URL with a parameter? O this parameter, imagine `www.example.net/public/registry/UNIQUE_URL`, will also affect the SEO?

Comment: I am sorry. Maybe it is just me. But I do not understand your question- the last 2 sentences. Can you clarify? Are you asking if a parameter or URL is better for search performance? If so, then the answer is easy. ;-)

Comment: This is exactly what canonical urls are for

Answer (score 1):

When you have many URLs that have the same content but with slight differences, you can use the [canonical link element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_link_element) to tell search engines about the duplication and tell them which URL is the preferred ("canonical") URL.

Each of your pages need to contain the following tag in the `head` section:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.example.net/public/registry" />
```